# How can I refer to element in Python?

Tags: python

The first step in my code is to specify the number of lines to enter. Then I enter the lines in the form of :

```
John 430.09 300.90 2070.00
```

And if I have for example 3 inputs how can I refer to the last value in every input line? I have to sum up these values.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
with open("your_document") as f:
    my_list = []   # this will save the last value of every line
    for x in f:
        my_list.append(float(x.strip().split()[-1])) 
    print sum(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some simple Python constructs:

`split` will turn a string into a list, splitting on the given delimiter (or whitespace, if you don't provide one):

```
>>> data = 'John 430.09 300.90 2070.00'
>>> data.split()
['John', '430.09', '300.90', '2070.00']
```

Indexing a list gives you the individual parts, and using a negative index will count from the end instead:

```
>>> data.split()[-1]
'2070.00'
```

Then you can cast that into a float, so you can add them up:

```
>>> float(data.split()[-1])
2070.0
```

You can loop over the input, and sum the results. Putting it together:

```
>>> data = '''John 430.09 300.90 2070.00
... Ben 530.10 200.50 3020.50'''
>>> result = sum(float(x.split()[-1]) for x in data.splitlines())
>>> result
5090.5
```

Comment: thanks! :) So, I introduce three separate line in the same form and now how can I merge these in one object ? At the end your post is object "data = '''John 430.09 300.90 2070.00 ... Ben 530.10 200.50 3020.50''' .

Comment: Why can I get this : data = '''John 430.09 300.90 2070.00
... Ben 530.10 200.50 3020.50''' ? why there are three ->> '  ?

Comment: I've used three quotes because that allows me to have a string split over multiple lines. Where does your data come from? You can replace `data.splitlines()` in my code with whatever item you have that iterates over each line at a time.